# JQuery: Submiting a form when image clicked doesn't work

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I need a form to be submitted when an image with id="searchbutton" is clicked. The HTML code is following:

```
<div id="searchform">
  <form action="/search" method="get" novalidate="novalidate">
    <input type="hidden" name="in" value="people">
    <input name="for" type="text">
    <input type="submit" class="hidden">
  </form>
  <img src="./search.png" alt="search" id="searchbutton">
</div>
```

My Jquery code is following

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $("#searchbutton").click(function () {
      $('#searchform').find('form:first').submit();
   });
</script>
```

Does anyone see, where the problem is?
Thanks!

Comment: `$(document).ready(function(){...});` is missing.

Comment: Have you tried putting the code inside **`$( document ).ready( handler )`** ??

Comment: Are you able to add a Id to form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#searchbutton").click(function () {
       $('#searchform form:first').submit();
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a form name say form_name then try this code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("image_id").onclick = function myfunction() 
  {         
document.form_name.submit();
}
```

here image_id is your image id.